# How to upload media (image, video) to Google Cloud Storage with Java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am now facing with a problem once uploading media files to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/) by using Google Cloud Storage API Java. To be more specific, the GCS API Java example just help us upload text files to Google Bucket but is not useful for media files. I also see some discussion from ticket: [Written file not showing up in Google Cloud Storage](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gs-discussion/TnqHFmFBC-4) that the team suggest to use a gsutil tool written by Python. I am not using blobstore as well

My question is how can I do with the following requirements:
-Creating and deleting buckets.
-Uploading, downloading, and deleting objects (such as media files).
-Listing buckets and objects.
-Moving, copying, and renaming objects.

by implementing with Java?

I thank you very much for your time and look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: There is no difference between text files and any other file types when it comes to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 2):

- **Upload/Download files:** you can use the [Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore) which can be configured to store blobs in Google Cloud Storage by specifying your bucket in the [BlobstoreService `createUploadUrl`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage). Similarly, to download you can create a `createGsBlobKey` with the Bucket name + Object name which can then be served by the Blobstore service.
- **Create/Delete buckets:** The [Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) does not offers a way to create/delete buckets. You will need to use Google Cloud Storage REST API to programatically [create](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/insert) and [delete](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/delete). Thought, you might want to consider organizing your data within one bucket.
- **Moving, copying, and renaming objects:** make use of the [Google Cloud Storage Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/)

Comment: @peterT np! glad this helps.

Comment: I try to use BloStore API as your recommendation. There is no error found, but I can't not see my picture in bucket. Could you show my where I can see it or my code has some mistakes.

Comment: I try to use BloStore API as your recommendation. There is no error found, but I can't not see my picture in bucket. Could you show my where I can see it or my code has some mistakes.

Comment: Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(request);
        BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");
        UploadOptions uploadOptions = null;
        uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("mybucket");
        String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload", uploadOptions);
        res.getWriter().println("URL:" + url);

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar requirement when I had to deal with all sorts of documents including media objects such as images and videos. This is the implementation I followed based on the official documentation of Google Cloud Examples project on GitHub:
[Source Link](https://github.com/dragonsbreath/GoogleCloudWrapper/blob/master/CloudStorage.java)

To Upload a file

```
 public boolean uploadFile(String filePath, byte[] file) {
        try {
            setDefaultStorageCredentials();
            storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, filePath).build(),
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(file));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

To download a file

```
public byte[] downloadFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    setDefaultStorageCredentials();     
    return storage.get(bucketName).get(filePath).getContent();
}
```

To delete a file

```
public boolean deleteFile(String filePath){
    setDefaultStorageCredentials();                     
    return storage.delete(storage.get(bucketName).get(filePath).getBlobId());       
}
```

To provide temporary access to a file using a signed URL

```
public String getTemporaryFileLink(String filePath) throws Exception{
        setDefaultStorageCredentials();     
        Blob blob = storage.get(bucketName).get(filePath);      
        String blobName = blob.getName();       
        URL signedUrl = storage.signUrl(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, blobName).build(), 5,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        return signedUrl.toExternalForm();
    }
```

Most of these methods are mentioned in this [Google Github project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java). I just removed the clutter in my implementation. Hope this helps.