# How to create new file on GCS bucket java

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to create a new file in one of my google cloud storage buckets.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(report.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
    GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKET_NAME, csvFileName);
    GcsFileOptions options = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
    GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
    copy(stream, Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
```

The code runs without errors, but the bucket remains empty.
I'm 99% sure that I wrote the code correctly (it works for me in another project), but the problem is about the GCS bucket settings. 
Thanks.

Comment: I have answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053593/6854069

Answer (score 1):

I think the question linked by Raghuram Kasyap should help, but just in case you wanted to use the [NIO Filesystem Provider for Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio), it would go like this:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(report.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
try (FileSystem fs = CloudStorageFileSystem.forBucket(BUCKET_NAME)) {
    Path dest = fs.getPath(filename);
    Files.copy(stream, dest);
}
```

The link above has the dependency you need to add to your project; it's part of google-cloud-java. I tried the code above and it worked for me.